# What is wrong with this TypeScript declaration?

Tags: typescript

I'm declaring this:

```
export interface Interface {
    func: string[][] => string[][];
}
```

And I'm getting this:

```
error TS1005: ';' expected.

func: string[][] => string[][];
                 ~~

error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

func: string[][] => string[][];
                    ~~~~~~

error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

func: string[][] => string[][];

error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

func: string[][] => string[][];

error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

}
~
```

What is the correct syntax here?

Comment: You need to define an argument name, eg `(arg: string[][])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow function '=>' creates an expression. An interface on another hand is a definition, so you would do it like so:

```
export interface Interface {
  func(arg: string[][]): string[][];
}
```